# How to open datePicker and set date on each row separately on edit button click

Tags: angular, typescript, datetimepicker, bootstrap-table

I have a table, where in eachrow i am having dateTimePicker in each row. And i have a edit button in each row.I want like "On edit button click dateTimePicker should open for that perticular row".I am using angular2 or more than that.
Below is my html code.

```
<table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>

          <th (click)="sort('name')">Name
            <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" *ngIf="key =='name'" [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
          </th>

          <th (click)="sort('genre')">Start Date &amp; Time
            <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" *ngIf="key =='genre'" [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
          </th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of data | let i = index">
          <td>{{data.name}}</td>

          <td><input placeholder="Date Time:"
            [(ngModel)]="dateTime"
            [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt" [owlDateTime]="dt">
     <owl-date-time #dt></owl-date-time>
          </td>

          <td class="editButton" (click)='editAction()'>
              <mat-icon style="vertical-align: middle">edit</mat-icon> Edit 
          </td>


        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
```

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime this datetimepicker.

This is my ts file code.

```
data = [
        { 
          "name": "name1"
        },
        { 

          "name": "name2"
        },
        {

          "name": "name3"
        }


  editAction(){
          //on edit button click
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be using an old version of Angular, because I don't believe your [`*ngFor="let data of data | let i = index"` syntax is valid for Angular v7](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) (the current version). If you are using an old version of Angular, then you might also be using an old version of `ng-pick-datetime` in which case who knows how valid the current documentation is. But the *current* documentation for `ng-pick-datetime` (which is intended to be used with Angular v7) [outlines how to do your exact request](https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker#how-to-use).

Looks like you should move the `[owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt"` directive to to the element you want to trigger the datetime picker. In your case, the edit button.

```
<td>
  <input placeholder="Date Time:" [(ngModel)]="dateTime" [owlDateTime]="dt">
  <owl-date-time #dt></owl-date-time>
</td>

<td class="editButton" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt">
  <mat-icon style="vertical-align: middle">edit</mat-icon> Edit 
</td>
```

Comment: I have solved the issue by following this example. @John
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-attribute-cmwyww?file=app%2Fapp.component.html